# How do I close the left menu?

Tags: interface, edit-mode

[image]

How do I close this menu? That is to the left of the "main screen" or "grid"

Answer (score 1):

To make things less confusing, let's make sure we use the same words for the same things.

For this, I highly recommend everyone to read [User Interface — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/interface/index.html). It contains all the official naming of Blender's UI elements, it makes things way easier to communicate when we use the same words for the same concepts ;)  And it also explains how to use the interface.

---

I guess what you are talking about is an [***Area***](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/interface/window_system/areas.html#:%7E:text=The%20Blender%20window%20is%20divided,a%20specific%20part%20of%20Blender.):

[image: area]

> The Blender window is divided up into a number of rectangles called Areas. Areas reserve screen space for Editors, such as the 3D Viewport, or the Outliner.

Conversely, here's an example of what we could actually call a [***Menu***](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/interface/controls/buttons/menus.html#ui-header-menu):

[image: menu example]

> Most headers exhibit a set of menus, located at the start of the header.

Areas in Blender can be split in two areas, or you can merge one area into another.

To merge an area, you can either <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> the line between the two areas and select *Merge*, or <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> drag the corner of an area into the neighbor area you want to merge into:

[image: how to merge]

> Dragging from an area corner outward will join two areas. The area that will be closed gets a dark overlaid arrow. You can select which area will be closed by moving the mouse over areas. Release the <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to complete the join. If you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> before releasing the mouse, the operation will be aborted.

Answer (score 0):

Hover your mouse over the right hand edge of the menu and you should get, I don't know the word, the left-right movement arrow icon showing up. Then left click and drag to the left, it'll collapse the menu and hide it.

This is true of any menu in Blender.